# How to map a column of a dataframe in an easy way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a dataframe 'df':

```
   id size
0   1   18
1   2   28
2   3   38
3   4   46
4   5   60
```

I want to map 'size' to str based on the rule:

```
size<25     -> 's'
25<=size<40 -> 'm'
size>=40    -> 'l'
```

The result should be:

```
   id size size_str
0   1   18        s
1   2   28        m
2   3   38        m
3   4   46        l
4   5   60        l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use np.where

```
df['size_str'] = np.where(df['size']<25, 's', np.where(df['size']<40, 'm', 'l'))
```

Comment: Could also `cut` to get a categorical variable which will also save some more nesting of where's if more sizes are added, eg: `pd.cut(df['size'], [float('-inf'), 25, 40, float('inf')], labels=list('sml'))`

Answer (score 2):

using `np.select`

```
conditions = [
    df['size'].lt(25),
    df['size'].ge(40)
]

df['size_str'] = np.select(conditions, ['s','1'], default='m')
```

---

**Result:**

```
    id  size    size_str
0   1   18      s
1   2   28      m
2   3   38      m
3   4   46      1
4   5   60      1
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as readability goes, the right way to do this would probably be to define a function and then `apply` it to the `size` column like so

```
def size2str(size):
    if size < 25:
        return 's'
    elif 25 <= size < 40:
        return 'm'
    else:
        return 'l'

df['size_str'] = df['size'].apply(size2str)
```